# App crashes when launching OpenFeint achievements page

Tags: iphone, openfeint, achievements

So I'm trying to make a button that launches the OpenFeint achievements page, but it always makes my app crash.
When I press the button it doesn't instantly crash, first it shows that it is loading the achievements page for about 5 seconds, and then crash.
To launch the achievements page, I use this method:

```
[OpenFeint launchDashboardWithAchievementsPage];
```

When I'm launching a specific leaderboard page, or even go to the achievements page from dashboard (instead of my custom achievements button), it doesn't crash.

But XCode does give me a warning for both achievements page launching method and leaderboard page launching method, it says that OpenFeint may not respond to that method.

Here's my leaderboard page launching method by the way:

```
[OpenFeint launchDashboardWithHighscorePage:@"ID"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was using an old version of OpenFeint.
In 2.7.3 they "Fixed a bug launching straight to the achievement's dashboard page".
I have updated my OpenFeint and that fixed it.